# Conditionally overriding an active model serializer association method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I’m writing a serializer that includes `has_one :source`. `source` can be a number of different types. I’m trying to make the JSON smaller when `source` is a `Foo` by [overriding the association methods](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails-api/active_model_serializers#Overriding_association_methods). I tried this:

```
def source
  return super unless source_type == 'Foo'
  render json: source, serializer: LimitedFooSerializer
end
```

But then I get ​*no superclass method `source’*.

Then I tried:

```
def source
  render json: source unless source_type == 'Foo'
  render json: source, serializer: LimitedFooSerializer
end
```

But that errors ​*stack level too deep*​; presumably it’s an infinite recursion.

How can I *conditionally* override the association method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the serializer directly worked:

```
def source
  if source_type == 'Foo'
    FooSerializer::LimitedFooSerializer.new(object.source)
  else
    object.source
  end
end
```

I had to use `object.source` instead of `source` to avoid the recursion.